# How does a recordable CD that uses organic dyes to store data produce iridescent rainbow colors?

Tags: interference, diffraction

I thought that only pressed pre-printed CD-ROM can produce rainbow colors due to the parallel spiral tracks of lands and pits it uses to store data in the reflective metal layer, tracks that diffract white light. But I see that even recordable CD-R we use to write data on our computers, the version of CD that uses organic dyes to store data produces iridescent rainbow colors, although the metal layer has no lands or pits. What is the mechanism behind rainbow colors in a recordable CD (CD-R)?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see the rainbow is that the optical path to the reflective layer and back is changing. This forms an interference pattern like the one on the surface of a soap bubble. In the bubble case the actual surface thickness is changing (note how it goes "black" just before it pops as it thins out). In the case of the CD, its the lands and grooves forming the differences.

The pits are too small to see with your eye. What you are seeing is the large-scale macroscopic pattern of all of them together. The issue is not the pattern of the bumps, but that they exist at all.

A recordable CD/DVD produces precisely the same pattern, but has different physics. In this case you still have changing path lengths, but now its due to the change in the dye layer. In this case it makes certain patches dark, so they do not reflect off the internal metal layer. That pattern of light and dark is exactly the same as the "normal" CD, so again at the macroscopic level the same pattern emerges.

Comment: I don't think the optical path changes due to bumps are the reason for the rainbow colors. After all, even clean CD with no data still produces rainbows. The changes of reflectivity of the aluminum in radial direction is a more likely reason. The data track lines are probably less reflective than the inter-track spaces. This makes the aluminum layer a diffraction grating. The colors are due to diffraction on this grating.